# Springboot ResultSetExtractor vs RowCallbackHandler skips first row

Tags: java, jdbctemplate

I have written below method in my ProductDaoImpl class. My springboot application is using postgres as DB to store product records which has fields like id, productname, price, quantity (it is simple basic/demo springboot with controller & dao layer with some additional functionality but from controller to dao layer just contains below method.) . I have added pom.xml for jar been used.

In some of the forum I learnt that RowCallbackHandler is good for large dataset so I was comparing RowCallbackHandler with ResultSetExtractor usage. Below "getProducts" method uses both RowCallbackHandler
& ResultSetExtractorapproach implementation in the same method. Both has printline statements to print records while iterating through resultset. I see that ResultSetExtractor is printing all the records including first one while RowCallbackHandler skips the first one.

I tried also with two records only & I see RowCallbackHandler skips the first records everytime even after clean build & restart while I do not see any issue with ResultSetExtractor, can someone please help me understand the issues or what needs to take care of.

**ProductDaoImpl**

```
  @Override
  public void getProducts() {
    
    
    List list = new ArrayList();
    String SQL = "select * from product";
    
    //ResultSetExtractor Implementation
       jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, 
        new ResultSetExtractor<List>(){
        
        public List extractData(
           ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
           
           while(rs.next()){  
             System.out.println("ResultSetExtractor ::" + rs.getString("productname"));
           }  
           return list;  
        }        
     });
    
    
    //RowCallbackHandler Implementation
       
    jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new RowCallbackHandler() {
      public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
          while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("RowCallbackHandler ::" + rs.getString("productname"));
              
          }
      }
    });
 
  }
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA-->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Security -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JWT -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Mail -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Devtools hotdeploy-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

`RowCallbackHandler` is called repeatedly by Spring, once for each row.

You must not write your own row processing loop within a `RowCallbackHandler`.  On each invocation from Spring, you process only the current row in `rs`.

```
jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new RowCallbackHandler() {
  public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("RowCallbackHandler ::" + rs.getString("productname"));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, yup removing resultset iteration indeed helped as it was unnecessary in new RowCallbackHandler way of implementation.